# Magento 2. Flush cache programmatically for particular block

Tags: magento2, block-cache

I'm creating catalog rule programmatically and I want to see update price block on category and product pages immediately after that. Is there way to flush cache for price block only?

Or what is the best solution here (use small ttl, etc)?